# Input type="number" - Not working in IE11 or Edge

Tags: html, validation, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, html-input

So I'm well aware that this may have been asked previously but having looked at many threads on the issue there seems to be no definitive answer.

https://jsfiddle.net/hbruun/qmd0vgr8/

```
<div class="mt10"><input type="number" required="true" min="6.4" max="9.0" step="0.1" value="6.9" /></div>
```

The above jsfiddle (not mine) is an example illustration how **input type="number"** is completely useless in both IE11 and Edge. It works as expected in chrome unsuprisingly, but I'm need of a fix to replace this so that the user is prevented from entering anything other than numeric characters.

Comment: Create a dropdown with the only choices being the numbers you want them to use, or use a regex to verify it was a number after input.

Comment: "completely useless" is not a technical description of a problem. What doesn't work? Also, the `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: @Rob - I'm sorry, by that I mean the type="number" does not do anything in IE. Compared with Chrome where it will limit my input to numeric characters

Answer (score 1):

Try to set 0 as min value, and magically it starts to work, but just in the scope of step, so, if step=0.1 -> 1.1 will be valid, 1.12 will not, when step=0.01 1.12 will be valid, 1.001 will not and so on. Min value would be checked in code ...

Answer (score -4):

```
<label>Granularity:&nbsp:<span id="outgranularity">6.9</span><br/><input type="range" required="true" min="6.4" max="9.0" step="0.1" value="6.9" onchange="updateOutput(event)" /></label>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @jj  & Rob - yes we all know that IE does not natively display or validate input on numeric input fields. I am suggesting that you use the range type instead or If you want to support IE9/10 as well use the jquery forms plugin instead.

Comment: type="range" doesn't work to input number only. Even it create a bar on screen which is weired.